# excel cannot complete this task due to pivottable cache

Tags: excel, vba, memory, pivot-table, excel-2013

Was getting excited as I finished up my excel macro, then my boss hands me a MUCH larger file to try and test. Size difference was from 15,000KB to 275,000KB. I just hoped that it would continue to run. I was wrong. I'm getting the "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources" error. So we tried running it on my co-workers 8core 16GB RAM machine. Thinking this will knock it out of the park. Nope. Same error, on the second pivot table this time though. SO, I'm assuming the error is in my pivottable function. Is there a way to clean up the creation of a pivottable like erasing the cache or something?

```
Function CPT(ByRef Location() As String, Name As String, Data As String, ByRef Filters() As     String, ByRef Rows() As String, ByRef Columns() As String _, ByRef Values() As String, ByRef Types() As String)
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        Data, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).createPivotTable _
        TableDestination:=Worksheets(Location(0)).Range(Location(1)), TableName:=Name, _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
    '/////////////////////////////////////////////
    'If it errors field name is probably incorrect
    '/////////////////////////////////////////////
    'Values
    If (Not IsArrayEmpty(Values())) Then
        For i = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
            If (Types(i) = "Max") Then
                ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Name).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                Name).PivotFields(Values(i)), "Max of " & Values(i), xlMax
            ElseIf (Types(i) = "Sum") Then
                ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Name).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                Name).PivotFields(Values(i)), "Sum of " & Values(i), xlSum
            ElseIf (Types(i) = "Min") Then
                ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Name).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                Name).PivotFields(Values(i)), "Min of " & Values(i), xlMin
            ElseIf (Types(i) = "Count") Then
                ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Name).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                Name).PivotFields(Values(i)), "Count of " & Values(i), xlCount
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    'Filters
    If (Not IsArrayEmpty(Filters())) Then
        For i = LBound(Filters) To UBound(Filters)
            With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Name).PivotFields(Filters(i))
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            End With
        Next i
    End If

    'Rows
    If (Not IsArrayEmpty(Rows())) Then
        For i = LBound(Rows) To UBound(Rows)
            With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Name).PivotFields(Rows(i))
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
            End With
        Next i
    End If

    'Columns
    If (Not IsArrayEmpty(Columns())) Then
        For i = LBound(Columns) To UBound(Columns)
            With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Name).PivotFields(Columns(i))
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            End With
        Next i
    End If


End Function
```

Is there a more effecient way to have a pivot table function? I have to create a lot so I didn't want to have to code this out for every single one.

Comment: Did you try manually to generate the pivot table? If the Excel file size is indeed 275 MB, I suspect Excel won't be able to handle a pivot table correctly. You may want to try generating the pivot table via a datasource querying your data sheet or an MS Access database generated from the data sheet.

Comment: If all of the macro is done manually everything works correctly. Although sometimes in struggles(my pc is ancient, the bossman won't have problems on his).

Comment: Did you try setting the `.ManualUpdate` property of the pivot table to `True` while adding/changing the fields? See http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/speeding-up-pivottable-updates/